# What is the fastest way to compare two values from different hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to compare two hashes to see if the values match so i can reconcile some data.

I have a hash of existing accounts and a hash of accounts i need to check if they exist based on the existing accounts to see if it needs to be inserted.

```
# Reconcile Adaccounts
def self.reconcileAdaccounts(ad_accounts, user_id)

    # These are the accounts that exist
    existing_accounts = FbAdaccount.active
                                    .select("fb_id")
                                    .where("user_id = ?", user_id)
                                    .as_json

    ad_accounts.each do |ad_account|

        if #here i would need to check if ad_account["account_id"] matches one of the existing records

            p "This one already exists"
            p ad_account["account_id"]
        else

            p "I need to create this one"
            p ad_account["account_id"]
        end

    end

end
```

I could have nested loops but that does not seem like it would be the best solution, i also tried looking for any rails API functions that could do this but i have not found one.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean an "array of existing hashes" and an "array of accounts I need to check"? :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're trying to create the model if they don't exist, correct? Are there other attributes in `FbAdaccount`, or just the id?

Comment: @UpvoteMe I have two hashes, each have a key => value for an ID i need to match on. So hash1 can be {"fb_id"=>"123", "fb_id"=>"456", "fb_id"=>"567"} and hash2 can be {"fb_id"=>"123", "fb_id"=>"456"} and i need to find the fb_id that is in hash1 but not in hash2

Comment: I can tell you're unfamiliar with Ruby (or maybe programming) but it's okay — that's why you're on a support forum. `{"fb_id"=>"123", "fb_id"=>"456", "fb_id"=>"567"}` isn't valid code, you probably mean `[{"fb_id"=>"123"}, {"fb_id"=>"456"}, {"fb_id"=>"567"}]`. That is an array, where each element is a hash.

Comment: @UpvoteMe just an example so you can see what i am trying to do, that was just some arbitrary values i came up with, i just want to know the fastest way to match values in two different ruby hashes

Comment: please join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187958/room-for-upvote-me-and-ricks) so that I can explain why your sample code is invalid Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by). I've additionally wrapped the call in a transaction so all of this hits the database just once — in a single query.

```
def self.reconcileAdaccounts(ad_accounts, user_id)
  FbAdaccount.transaction do
    ad_accounts.each do |ad_account|
      FbAdaccount.active
                 .select('fb_id')
                 .where('user_id = ?', user_id)
                 .find_or_create_by(ad_account['account_id'])
    end
  end
end
```

### Transactions

A transaction doesn't magically alter the query, but it wraps it together so that it either all happens together, or doesn't happen at all.

With the following code:

```
numbers = (3..7).to_a

Ear.transaction do
  numbers.each do |number|
    Ear.find_or_create_by(bla: number)
  end
end
```

Note the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements. They signify where the call starts and ends.

```
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Ear Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Ear Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 3], ["created_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.157989"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.157989"]]
Ear Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Ear Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 4], ["created_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.160838"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.160838"]]
Ear Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Ear Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 5], ["created_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.162241"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.162241"]]
Ear Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Ear Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 6], ["created_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.163794"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.163794"]]
Ear Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Ear Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 7], ["created_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.165589"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-05 23:17:28.165589"]]
 (40.9ms)  COMMIT
```

Now here's the same code, just without a transaction to wrap it in:

```
numbers = (20..25).to_a

numbers.each do |number|
  Ear.find_or_create_by(bla: number)
end
```

Note the total number `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` messages:

```
Ear Load (249.3ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(73.4ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (48.7ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 20], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:35.754374"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:35.754374"]]
(79.8ms)  COMMIT
Ear Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (77.7ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 21], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:35.918461"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:35.918461"]]
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
Ear Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (2.7ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 22], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.003822"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.003822"]]
(110.1ms)  COMMIT
Ear Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 23], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 23], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.125187"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.125187"]]
(37.0ms)  COMMIT
Ear Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 24], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 24], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.168414"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.168414"]]
(72.4ms)  COMMIT
Ear Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "ears".* FROM "ears" WHERE "ears"."bla" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["bla", 25], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(1.7ms)  BEGIN
Ear Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "ears" ("bla", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["bla", 25], ["created_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.249285"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-06 00:12:36.249285"]]
(121.2ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Hey, i tried this and it ran a select statement for every ad account

Comment: @RickS it would, because it will execute many SELECT statements, but they're all wrapped together. I'll edit the answer to illustrate.